# Using phonegap, is there a way for an Android device to communicate with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, cordova

I have a php page which connects an API and gets information back which can then be displayed.

I'd like to turn this into an app for Android. I've heard of PhoneGap, which I know uses javascript, html, and css. I know javascript is capable of calling php files, but I am unsure how or if its even possible to call a php file from an android device. I'm not sure if android  browsers can handle php, or what the deal is with them. So if you have any information on that, I'd appreciate it.

I'm also willing to rewrite the API call in javascript, but I don't think thats possible. If  you think differently, please let me know what you're talking about.

Comment: Here you mean talking(AJAX) OR actually running a PHP server on your android device?

Comment: I don't think I could run PHP on the actual device. Which leads me to AJAX. But because the PHP would be on the phone would it crash? the php is not on a server anywhere I could contact really... well I guess my local machine, but I'm very uncertain how to set that up since I have a dynamic IP address

Comment: ?? Cant you just use 127.0.0.1 the GREAT localhost address. this is a group of address which will rebound to your own system.. you just to set up a server there.. im assuming this is just for development purposes

Comment: Why would you put PHP on the device?? No, you need to put it on a server that is accessible via the web and then your device will need web access.

Comment: @parvSharma I'm trying to use a mobile device. If I used the localhost address then it would not contact my computer since that would not be the localhost.

Comment: @theZ Without a static IP how  would I insure that the app can always communicate? or is there no way other than using a static IP?

Comment: Static is the easier way to go. Either find a free way or pay for server space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android cannot talk directly to PHP. What phonegap, javascript, etc.. are doing is simply issuing HTTP requests that happen to be handled by a PHP script.

The PHP code will execute, output some data (json, html, xml, gif, jpg, etc...) and send that out as a the HTTP request's reply.

Comment: So if the php is not on a server (its currently just on my local machine), and I upload that php to the android device to make it run, will it crash? or will phonegap take care of it?

Comment: There won't be a PHP interpreter on the android device, so the php file will just be some random text garbage. It'd be no different than (say) uploading a Windows .cmd/.bat file to Android and expecting it to run.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was expecting. There's just so much out there about downloading php for android, I wasn't sure if it was standard at this point. So do you have any tips on how I can accomplish my goal then?

Comment: there'll likely never be a PHP interpreter that runs under android. But it is very easy to set up a web service powered by PHP that you can issue http requests to from android and have PHP process the request.

Comment: I use xampp right now. Is this what you're referencing? and if so, how do I fix the issue of my dynamic IP address? or is there anyway?

Comment: yeah, xammp is apache+mysql+php. That's a standard stack. For dynamic IPs, there's plenty of services that allow dynamic updates, I use dyndns.org for my home cable connection.

Comment: what you're saying makes sense. I think I need just one more piece of the puzzle. I am developing the app in Eclipse. I do not want to place the php code into the Android Project. I instead want to (for the time of development at least) connect to my localhost IP, send it the information it needs, have it run the query on the API and then send back the result?

Comment: Run it as two separate proejcts in eclipse then. android/client and php/server.

Answer (score 2):

`PHP` is just a server side language so it doesn't matter if your browser "can or cannot" handle it, only `HTML` is returned (unless you set a different content-type).

You may be worth while looking into `REST` style `JSON` api's which would allow a XMLRequest to be sent to. Have a look at [this document](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile)

Theres also a [nice tutorial](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/05/calling-the-rest-api-from-javascript-in-phonegap.html) here which shows how to call a `REST` API and a [PHP Tutorial](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) here to create a `REST` API.

Comment: I will look at that link in a moment. But I'm curious, if my php is not necessarily "published", and I load it up on the android device, will phonegap take care of it? or will it crash? I am concerned because it wouldn't necessarily be running via web

Comment: Phone-gap doesn't run PHP, you would need to put this on your own webserver and call it.

Answer (score 0):

1.It dosent matter to PhoneGap where the PHP is hosted or Its PHP OR ASP.NET OR ASP.NET MVC
2.If You wanna host your PHP code yourself in production (You mayb shouldn't do this in production). then you need a server and a static IP address
3.if you just wanna setup a PHP server for developmental purposes then just tie it to 127.0.0.1:81 and you can directly use this address it doesn't matter whether you have a static IP address or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with phonegap using jsonp
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
Works great